# Meaning of IPTABLE duplicate values

Tags: linux, iptables, tcp, sockets, redis

I'm new to IPTABLES and when I execute the following command

```
/sbin/iptables --list -n | grep 16381
```

I could see multiple entries as shown below :

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  a.b.c.d         0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:16381
ACCEPT     tcp  --  a.b.c.d         0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:16381
ACCEPT     tcp  --  a.b.c.e         0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:16381
ACCEPT     tcp  --  a.b.c.b         0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:16381
ACCEPT     tcp  --  a.b.c.f         0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:16381
ACCEPT     tcp  --  a.b.c.f         0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:16381
ACCEPT     tcp  --  a.b.c.c         0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:16381
ACCEPT     tcp  --  a.b.c.g         0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:16381
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0       0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:16381
```

Can someone explain the reason for duplicate entries ?

I'm completely new to this , so detailed explanation would be very much appreciated.

Comment: How are you loading your `iptables`'s rules? Are you using `iptables-restore`, or using some kind of script? Looks to me that you loaded that command/script twice without flushing the content previously

Comment: How to ensure that flush has happened before executing again ?

Comment: Are you using a script?

Comment: `iptables -L` does not necessarily show all match criteria. Use `iptables-save` to inspect the full rules. Also note how `grep` does allow you to see in which chain the rules are contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably running a script (or similar) which adds rules, but don't delete the old ones. Note that adding the same rule many times will make `iptables` add them as many times as you execute the script, even if the rules already exist.

If you're using a script, make sure to clear all rules before you add new rules again. Put something like this on the top:

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -Z
```

Note that these commands only clear the default table, which is `filter`. If you had rules on more than one table, you need to execute the same commands on that table. For example:

```
iptables -F -t nat
iptables -X -t nat
iptables -Z -t nat
```

Also note that there are several tables: filter, nat, mangle, raw and security, however this doesn't mean you have to use all of them, just the ones you need.

However, the best approach is to use the `iptables-save` and `iptables-restore` commands, which save the states of the rules additionally to the rules themselves.

You could save your rules as:

```
iptables-save > /root/my-rules.iptables
```

You could even add rules to that saved file manually, although using native `iptables` commands is recommended and then dump the whole chains.

And then restore them with:

```
iptables-restore < /root/my-rules.iptables
```

Comment: Thank You so much for the detailed explanation. I'll explore and learn more about iptables.